# How to set attributes for a variable in R?

Tags: r, attributes

How do I assign an attribute to a variable? For eg.

```
> x <- rpart(f.la, mydata)
```

assigns the attributes:

```
$names
[1] "frame"               "where"              
[3] "call"                "terms"              
[5] "cptable"             "method"             
[7] "parms"               "control"            
[9] "functions"           "numresp"            
[11] "splits"              "variable.importance"
[13] "y"                   "ordered"            

$xlevels
named list()

$ylevels
[1] "cancelled"    "cart-abandon" "purchased"    "returned"    

$class
[1] "rpart"
```

Like this, I want to create attributes for a variable and assign a value to that attribute.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Alternatively to using `attributes` ([see the answer by @CathG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27547064/1560062))  you can use `attr`. The first will work on `NULL` objects but the second one won't. When you work with R attributes you have to remember there are not a simple as they look and can have some interesting side affects. Quick example:

```
> x <- 1:10
> class(x)
[1] "integer"
> x
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

So far so good. Now lets set `dim` attribute

```
> attr(x, 'dim') <- c(2, 5)
> class(x)
[1] "matrix"
> x
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    3    5    7    9
[2,]    2    4    6    8   10
```

`class` attribute is fundamental part of the [S3 classes](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html#s3):

```
> foo <- list()
> foo
list()
```

Lets see what happens if we set attribute `class` as a `'data.frame'`

```
> attr(foo, 'class') <- 'data.frame'
> foo
data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
```

or we can define custom behavior (BTW this behavior is a reason why it is better to avoid dots when define functions):

```
> print.foo <- function(x) cat("I'm foo\n")
> attr(foo, 'class') <- 'foo'
> foo
I'm foo
```

Other attributes like `comment` and `names` have also special meaning and constraints.
Take away message here is you have to a little bit careful when you work with attributes in R. One simple idea how to deal with is to use prefixes as artificial namespaces:

```
> x <- 1:10
> attr(x, 'zero323.dim') <- c(2, 5)
> class(x)
[1] "integer"
> x
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
attr(, 'zero323.dim')
[1] 2 5
```

In my opinion it particularly useful when you use third party libraries. Usage of the attributes is usually poorly documented, especially when used for some internal tasks, and it is pretty easy to introduce some hard to diagnose bugs if you use conflicting names.

Answer (score 17):

If you have a variable :

```
x<-"some variable"
```

you can do

```
attributes(x)$myattrib<-"someattributes"

> x
[1] "some variable"
attr(,"myattrib")
[1] "someattributes"
```

or

```
> attributes(x)
$myattrib
[1] "someattributes"
```