# set multiple attributes to a variable inside a function

Tags: r

I am trying to set attributes inside a function:

```
RFliq=function(x,tx.aa,a,ir) {
  if(a>50) a=a/365
  l1=x*((1-ir)*(1+tx.aa)^a+ir)
  attributes(l1)$ir <- ir*x*((1+tx.aa)^a-1)
  attributes(l1)$tx.ef.aa <- (l1/x)^(1/a)
  # attr(l1,'ir') <- ir*x*((1+tx.aa)^a-1)
  # attr(l1,'tx.ef.aa') <- (l1/x)^(1/a)
  return(l1)}
```

But the result "nest" the attributes:

```
RFliq(10000,.1335,2,.15)
[1] 12420.99
attr(,"ir")
[1] 427.2334
attr(,"tx.ef.aa")
[1] 1.114495
attr(,"tx.ef.aa")attr(,"ir")
[1] 427.2334
```

How can I avoid applying a attribute over another attribute?
[This question did not help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27546901/how-to-set-attributes-for-a-variable-in-r)

Comment: `structure(1, ir = 1, tx.ef.aa = 2)`

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to extract the value of `l1` in your second attribute assignment with `[]`:

```r
RFliq=function(x,tx.aa,a,ir) {
  if(a > 50) a = a / 365
  l1=x*((1-ir)*(1+tx.aa)^a+ir)
  attributes(l1)$ir <- ir*x*((1+tx.aa)^a-1)
  attributes(l1)$tx.ef.aa <- (l1[1]/x)^(1/a)
  return(l1)
}

RFliq(10000, 0.1335, 2, 0.15)
#> [1] 12420.99
#> attr(,"ir")
#> [1] 427.2334
#> attr(,"tx.ef.aa")
#> [1] 1.114495
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Provide your attributes in a *named* `list`:

```r
RFliq <- function(x, tx.aa, a,ir) {
    if(a > 50) a <- a/365
    l1 <- x * ((1 - ir) * (1+tx.aa)^a + ir)
      attributes(l1) <- 
        list(
          ir = ir * x * ((1 + tx.aa)^a - 1),
          tx.ef.aa = (l1/x)^(1/a)
        )
      return(l1)
    }
```

```
RFliq(10000, .1335,2, .15)
[1] 12420.99
attr(,"ir")
[1] 427.2334
attr(,"tx.ef.aa")
[1] 1.114495
```